# Android adb forward and own bridge to reach remote server

Tags: android, sockets, networking, tcp

i have a question about the adb forwarder stuff

My situation:

- Ressources: 1 Windows PC where i write my code, 1 Android device (Android 2.2) connected via USB to the Windows PC, 1 Linux Server running inside a virtual Machine (VMWare) on the Windows PC
- Task: the android device has to connect the virtual Machine via TCP (Port 65001)
- restrictions: I am not allowed to use wlan for that (because of some issues that i can't influence). I am not able to do usb (reverse) tethering because my devices does not have the usb tethering option in the android menu (disabled by the manufacturer).

I am able to telnet the port to the virtual machine (`telnet 192.168.1.2 65001`) and get my data. So there are no network problems between local and virtual machine. The local ip address is 192.168.1.1.

Now i need a bridge from the incoming port 65000 to the listening Port on the virtual machine (65001). I have used the following command `adb forward tcp:65000 tcp:65000` to get a tcp connection over usb from my android device to my localhost (and vice versa). As I know you can't forward with adb to a remote machine.

**Now the problem is that i can't bridge from 127.0.0.1:65000 to any other port to get the full communication path. If I try to create a listening connection on 127.0.0.1:6500 i get an error with the message that the port is already bind** (because of `adb forward tcp:65000 tcp:65000`). If the forward blocks all other connection on this port, how can i get the incoming data from the android device?

I've tried to tunnel via putty (localhost:65000 (win) -> server:65001) and I've written a little program that creates a listening server (socket) on 127.0.0.1:65000 and sends the information to 192.168.1.2:65001 via 192.168.1.1:65001.

Has anybody an idea how to solve my situation? If so please explain. Maybe this helps others too to handle the adb forwarding function.

hint: The Ports and addresses are only examples. The only fix port number is the listening port on the virtual machine

Comment: Did you managed to solve this?